# Sharing Draft.js toolbar across multiple editors?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm struggling to figure out how to make a single toolbar work across multiple editors - Only the current editor in focus should be effected by the toolbar. Is this possible? Is there a good example out there for Draft.js?

Answer (score 0):

### What you can do is:

It is good to have global state in use for this case

(for React hooks)
Pass your toolbar the state and setState for your editor.

When you focus on editor dispatch the state and setState for that editor to global state and make Toolbar subscribe to it.

also for the editor whenever state changes, you need to update the global state as well.

by this you will achieve managing editors from one toolbar.

I recommend you to not use Redux Toolkit as your global state library. Because when you will try to save the state it will throw an error (EditorState is nonserializable).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).